# Encountered an error (BadGateway) from host runtime on deploying a new Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I have the following ARM template for deploying Azure Function Apps:

```
module functionAppTemplate_F 'functionApp.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppTemplate-F'
  params: {    
  }
  dependsOn: [
    servicePlanTemplate
  ]
}

module functionAppSlotTemplate_F 'functionAppSlot.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppSlotTemplate-F'
  params: {    
  }
  dependsOn: [
    functionAppTemplate_F
  ]
}
```

On running this, I see "Encountered an error (BadGateway) from host runtime on deploying a new Azure Function App". What am I missing?

[Here](https://github.com/lipalath-ms/bicep/blob/main/template.bicep) is the bicep file

[image]

Comment: Please try to remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` from App.setting

Comment: could you share your bicep module files as well please? It will help try to reproduce the issue. Thanks